# Process redirect in Javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect, httpclient

I use `HttpClient 4.3.4.`

I make `POST` request - site in turn makes a few redirects (code page 302), which handled by `HttpClient` automatically (use `LaxRedirectStrategy`) by `HttpClient`. At the end I get HTML page (code 200) with the title `Redirection ...`. In its content there is the Javascript code with redirection on some URL. This redirection is not (of course) handled by `HttpClient`.
I tried to parse this page to get the URL make appropriate GET request (similar to browser) but site return HTML page with error (although I do not understand why this happens).

Is there is some way to handle redirects in Javascript?

Comment: window.location.href="filename?queryString"

Comment: HttpClient? Is this Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HttpClient` is a library that handles the HTTP protocol for you. It's not supposed to handle the content transfered by the protocol. The content, HTML and javascript, needs to be processed by a real browser or some simplified version of a browser.

You can either try to parse and execute the javascript yourself using an embedded javascript engine, or start a real browser. For the later option I recommend [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/), a web browser automation tool.

Your approach is brittle since it depends on the specific rediction logic used by the content at the time you wrote the parsing code. As for why it fails, there could be complications in the javascript yet to be discovered.

Comment: Thanks for recommendation - i think that Selenium is waht I need